# Can I set/use Nodejs environment in a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, websocket, electron

Here is my specific problem: I want to use a custom http.agent for a websocket connection using engine.io-client. The problem is, I'm using electron, therefore I'm in a chromium environment, and I can't use a custom http.agent outside a nodejs environnement

> agent (http.Agent): http.Agent to use, defaults to false ***(NodeJS only)***

Any idea how to 'simulate' a nodejs environnement if I'm in a browser?

hope I'm clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Electron is both a browser **and** a node.js environment, so yes you can use it.

Comment: Well, if what you say is true, I redirect you to my basic problem: why I'm not able to use https-proxy-agent on engine.io-client in electron? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208827/websocket-connection-through-proxy   .  Thx for the fast answer!